# Русский речевой этикет

Tags: общие-вопросы, этикет

В любом живом языке каждый день происходят какие-либо изменения. Часть из них касается речевого этикета. Например, формулы приветствия, прощания, благодарности, пожелания и т. п. Хотелось бы узнать, какие изменения в речевом этикете на рубеже ХХ-ХХI веков вы могли бы выделить? Что вы думаете об этих изменениях? Возможно ли выделить определённый ряд причин, повлекших изменения в ту или иную сторону?

Comment: Ну и вопрос Вы задали. Изменения в России - о да, произошли, и неизбежно повлияли как на язык, так и на этикет. Это тема для многих исследований.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Частица в 1-м значении — ДА, как «простейшее на первый взгляд слово, (в котором) много интересного и даже таинственного)* — http://otvet.expert/slovo-da-kakaya-chast-rechi-1458973 — имеет обыкновение употребляться в вопросе *Да или нет?* или *Ведь да?* в укороченном виде ***Да?*** Примеров печатных не найду, да и не найти, потому что слова-паразиты отлавливаются, а вживую их часто слышно: за минутную речь их бывает с десяток.

*«Есть тонкая ткань — да? — между лоббизмом и непредвзятостью»; «Как писала советская пропаганда, — да? — проявлялся массовый героизм людей»* и т. п. (С пунктуацией, пардон, тут уж... как смог.)

Частотность этого явления можно объяснить нежеланием отступать от агитационно-наступательной сути речи. Говорящий придаёт убедительности словам, перетягивает слушателя на свою сторону, периодически столбит уместность своей часто нескладной терминологии: *ну ведь это так, ну, согласитесь, ведь так же?*

Вторым пунктиком, наводящим ужас в речевом обороте текст, является фразеологизм ***На самом деле***, тот его вариант, который открывает повествование или абзац. Это выглядит забавно, как вызов на ровном месте. «Только вошёл, ничего не успел сделать»... А тебе уже возражает или назидательно указывает на истину тот, кого ты ещё толком не разглядел. Удивляет и поражает разговор попеременно упражняющихся в этом занятии граждан.

Третий пункт. *Расстрел, эвакуация, таран, тренинг...* С лёгкой руки малоинформированных СМИ неизвестные ***расстреливают*** на людной улице или в кафе горожан, наряду с людьми и вместо них ***эвакуируют*** школы и стадионы, автомобили ***таранят*** жилые дома и опоры мостов, войска тренируются, а не учатся на сборах... Эта проблема, употребление слов как карта ляжет, — вклад радио и ТВ, отечественного и не только.

Всё как-то можно объяснить. Но вот это — не смогу: «12 апреля 1961 года Ю. Гагарин на корабле "Восток" совершил первый полёт человека в космос».

Answer (score 0):

Из заметных для меня изменений - сдвоенное прощание "пока-пока" (возможно, это как-то связано  с английским bye-bye), дежурное телевизионное прощание "берегите себя (и своих близких)" и более старое "оставайтесь с нами" (при перерыве на рекламу).

Под влиянием телевидения и появляющейся в его эфире публики меняется и употребление некоторых выражений, не связанных с этикетом. Лет пять назад я обратил  внимание на агрессивное использование оборота "в том числе", которое ранее в ряде контекстов (без предварительного упоминания общего понятия, вместо выражения "в частности") считалось абсолютно безграмотным. Начиналось же это с политических ток-шоу, где стремятся переговорить друг друга сильными риторическими аргументами - вставленное в случайном месте "в том числе" может означать: у меня в запасе есть ещё, чем вам ответить. Теперь так говорят многие и по любому поводу, хотя старые журналисты (напр. В. Познер) такого себе не позволяют - в их словарном запасе есть выражения "в частности", "в числе /среди/ прочего". Но практика нового употребления выражения уже выглядит необратимо сложившейся. Выражением "в том числе" стали даже отвечать на вопрос, требующий ответа "да/нет" (как бы на всякий случай), с него чуть ли не начинают предложения ("я вам в том числе вот что скажу...") и т. п.

Comment: «Вставленное в случайном месте "в том числе"». ==== Нужно ли говорить о таких мелочах? «Лысое чмо» в адрес заклятого любимца всех ток-шоу — вот это уровень изменения. О том, что происходит за кадром, можно лишь догадываться. А «Тьфу на тебя» господина Усманова? Это вам не это... «пока пока».

Comment: Ничего себе "мелочь" - у половины страны язык заплетается и скоро придётся фиксировать элемент косноязычия как норму. А вот на банальное злословие, к счастью, у нормальных людей есть иммунитет. Никто ведь не бросился вслед за дипломатом по каждому поводу орать ближнему "в глаза мне смотри, чо взгляд отводишь!".

Comment: "На самом деле" в плане хамства слабовато. "Я тебе могу сказать вот что" - правда, это только разговорное, но потяжелее. Режет слух " и так далее", особенно в конце неумело построенного синонимического ряда.